# Oracle Virtual box, python3 in ubuntu 16

Tags: python3

I have downloaded ububntu16 in virtual box. I wanted to use anaconda. So I downloaded it for linux, the python 3 version. However when I type anaconda-navigator it is not launching, instead it says not found. However, i can see anaconda3 folder downloaded in Home. Please help.

Comment: Perhaps you did not install it. Look in the folder for instructions to install it.

Comment: I installed it too, using bash ./<filename>.sh